# How to load configuration variables in rails via yaml files

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I am trying to use an environment variable in `config/database.yml`.

This is my `local_env.yml`:

```
# Local Environment Variables
MYSQL_SOCK: "/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

Then I check if it is correct with the `rails console` and sure enough:

```
>> irb(main):002:0> ENV["MYSQL_SOCK"]
=> "/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

However in `config/database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: ENV["MYSQL_SOCK"]
```

I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'ENV["MYSQL_SOCK"]' (2)
```

But...

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: "/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

`works!`

What is going wrong?

Comment: You will need to define it in our .bashrc file. Which operating system you are using ?

Comment: @AmanGarg Aren't `local_env.ml` and system environment variables recognized as the same thing by rails?

Comment: values defined in local_env.yml are not recognized as system environment variables. Was your problem solved with below explaination in  answer ?

Comment: Use ERB tags around the environment variables like this:

    `socket: "<%= ENV['MYSQL_SOCK'] %>"`

Answer (score 0):

**This practise is generally followed for defining configuration variables like app ids, secret keys, s3 credentials etc and this file is put in `.gitignore`.**

Create a yml file with `settings.yml` (generally) or `local_env.yml`. Then define your keys according to environment.

```
development:
  MYSQL_SOCK: "/tmp/mysql.sock"
production:
  MYSQL_SOCK: "file path here"
```

And then load it via initializers. **Create a file name "0_load_config.rb" inside your initializers directory.** '0' is added in filename because this file should be loaded first then other initializers.

Then load `local_env.yml` file in a constant

```
LOCAL_ENV = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/local_env.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Then you can access this variable in your application. You can check via rails console also:

```
LOCAL_ENV["MYSQL_SOCK"]
```

It will give you the vaue which you had provided in `local_env.yml` i.e "/tmp/mysql.sock".